# Separar 1 variable en 2 cuando encuentre un Guion JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cordial Saludo.

Les comento lo que deseo hacer.

Ejemplo, tengo una variable asi:

```
var id = "673728-882";
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es que me separe eso en 2 variables donde esta el guion, ejemplo de como deberia quedar:

```
 var id2 = "673728";
  var id3 = "882";
```

Espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar.

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta con el metodo split de js. casi todos los lenguajes cuentan con ese metodo, solo debes de pasar como parametro la variable que deseas "suprimir"

```
    var id = "673728-882";
    var res = id.split("-");
// accedes con indices al vector que se creo con la variable res
    console.log(res[0]);
    console.log(res[1]);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[1];
```

espero haberte ayudado.
saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funcionó